# To perform this action, you need authorization

Tags: google-apps-script

Tell me please what changed the Google script, all scripts with HtmlService, after a new publication or when viewing the latest version of the code give an error - To perform this action, you need authorization. Where to make authorizations. So far, everything worked well.

According to this documentation, scripts are made [file-open_dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs)

CODE.GS

```
    /**
 * Creates a custom menu in Google Sheets when the spreadsheet opens.
 */
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Picker')
      .addItem('Start', 'showPicker')
      .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Displays an HTML-service dialog in Google Sheets that contains client-side
 * JavaScript code for the Google Picker API.
 */
function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Picker.html')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(425)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file');
}

/**
 * Gets the user's OAuth 2.0 access token so that it can be passed to Picker.
 * This technique keeps Picker from needing to show its own authorization
 * dialog, but is only possible if the OAuth scope that Picker needs is
 * available in Apps Script. In this case, the function includes an unused call
 * to a DriveApp method to ensure that Apps Script requests access to all files
 * in the user's Drive.
 *
 * @return {string} The user's OAuth 2.0 access token.
 */
function getOAuthToken() {
  DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}
```

PICKER.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
  <script>
    // IMPORTANT: Replace the value for DEVELOPER_KEY with the API key obtained
    // from the Google Developers Console.
    var DEVELOPER_KEY = 'ABC123 ... ';
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {width: 600, height: 425};
    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    /**
     * Loads the Google Picker API.
     */
    function onApiLoad() {
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': function() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
      }});
     }

    /**
     * Gets the user's OAuth 2.0 access token from the server-side script so that
     * it can be passed to Picker. This technique keeps Picker from needing to
     * show its own authorization dialog, but is only possible if the OAuth scope
     * that Picker needs is available in Apps Script. Otherwise, your Picker code
     * will need to declare its own OAuth scopes.
     */
    function getOAuthToken() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker)
          .withFailureHandler(showError).getOAuthToken();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Picker that can access the user's spreadsheets. This function
     * uses advanced options to hide the Picker's left navigation panel and
     * default title bar.
     *
     * @param {string} token An OAuth 2.0 access token that lets Picker access the
     *     file type specified in the addView call.
     */
    function createPicker(token) {
      if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            // Instruct Picker to display only spreadsheets in Drive. For other
            // views, see https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews
            .addView(google.picker.ViewId.SPREADSHEETS)
            // Hide the navigation panel so that Picker fills more of the dialog.
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            // Hide the title bar since an Apps Script dialog already has a title.
            .hideTitleBar()
            .setOAuthToken(token)
            .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
            // Instruct Picker to fill the dialog, minus 2 pixels for the border.
            .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,
                DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
      } else {
        showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
      }
    }

    /**
     * A callback function that extracts the chosen document's metadata from the
     * response object. For details on the response object, see
     * https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/result
     *
     * @param {object} data The response object.
     */
    function pickerCallback(data) {
      var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
      if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
            '<b>You chose:</b><br>Name: <a href="' + url + '">' + title +
            '</a><br>ID: ' + id;
      } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Picker canceled.';
      }
    }

    /**
     * Displays an error message within the #result element.
     *
     * @param {string} message The error message to display.
     */
    function showError(message) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + message;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick='getOAuthToken()'>Select a file</button>
    <p id='result'></p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I delete these functions from the code, it starts displaying HTML.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Picker')
      .addItem('Start', 'showPicker')
      .addToUi();
}
 function onApiLoad() {
          gapi.load('picker', {'callback': function() {
            pickerApiLoaded = true;
          }});
         }
```

What's interesting is if these functions are commented out, it does not help to correctly display HTML, and if it's to remove it starts to display.

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbybeJehYuPwQvhbaNViClAflBZVg6AV0Dh60Z-4RYA/dev

Comment: just run the onOpen function from the script editor,you will be prompted for authorization if required

Comment: Many thanks, your help!